# How do I use an IF statement in a loop with StringTemplate

Tags: c#, .net, stringtemplate, templating-engine

This displays nothing:

> $Articles:{
>             $if(i!=1)$
>             display in between articles
>             $endif$
>             $it.Text
>           }

This displays as expected

> $Articles:{
>             display in between articles
>             $it.Text
>           }

Any ideas on how to get this working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to compute all expressions and push into the template.  You are clearly filtering, which shoul be done in the model not the view.  Please see:

http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~parrt/papers/mvc.templates.pdf

Terence

Answer (score 0):

[here](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ST/Conditionally+included+subtemplates), it says that $if tests for the presence of an attribute or evaluates a boolean expr. The only operator allowed is `!(NOT)`,
so maybe you can define a boolean variable = (i!=1) and use it in the $if statement.

Comment: yeah I saw that, don't know how I can create a boolean value within a loop as a global one would be no use to me.

The i value represents the current iteration.